# How can I delete spam messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have the following event which prevents spamming in discord and automatically mutes spammer. I took that code from [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmbhnAFzxDI). Here's the code:

```
const usersMap = new Map();
const LIMIT = 10;
const TIME = 10000;
const DIFF = 4500;
client.on('message', async(message) => {
if(message.author.bot) return;
if(usersMap.has(message.author.id) && !message.member.roles.cache.has(staffId)) {
    const userData = usersMap.get(message.author.id);
    const { lastMessage, timer } = userData;
    const difference = message.createdTimestamp - lastMessage.createdTimestamp;
    let msgCount = userData.msgCount;
    console.log(difference);

    if(difference > DIFF) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        console.log('Cleared Timeout');
        userData.msgCount = 1;
        userData.lastMessage = message;
        userData.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            usersMap.delete(message.author.id);
            console.log('Removed from map.')
        }, TIME);
        usersMap.set(message.author.id, userData)
    }
    else {
        ++msgCount;
        if(parseInt(msgCount) === LIMIT) {
            let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');
            if(!muterole) {
                try{
                    muterole = await message.guild.roles.create({
                        name : "Muted",
                        permissions: []
                    })
                    message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
                        await channel.createOverwrite(muterole, {
                            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                            ADD_REACTIONS : false
                        })
                    })
                }catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            }
            message.member.roles.add(muterole);
            message.channel.send(`${message.author.tag} has been muted for potential spam.`);
            setTimeout(() => {
                message.member.roles.remove(muterole);
            }, TIME);
        } else {
            userData.msgCount = msgCount;
            usersMap.set(message.author.id, userData);
        }
    }
}
else {
    let fn = setTimeout(() => {
        usersMap.delete(message.author.id);
        console.log('Removed from map.')
    }, TIME);
    usersMap.set(message.author.id, {
        msgCount: 1,
        lastMessage : message,
        timer : fn
    });
}
})
```

And now to the question, how can I make the bot delete spam messages? Basically, how can I delete all spam messages for one time?

I tried but got confused.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to be more specific about what's troubling you.

Comment: Are you getting any **errors**?

Comment: @Toasty no, code works fine

Comment: @bruhbruh Okay, but StackOverflow is not a place where we write code for you. You should at least try this out by yourself and if you're getting any errors, you can ask for help :)

Comment: @Toasty I know this, but I just don't know how to, um, delete all the spam messages for one time. I do not ask you to code it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fetch a certain amount of messages and filter it so you're only getting messages sent by the spammer then pass them to bulkDelete()

Here is a little example:

```
message.channel.messages.fetch({
  limit: 100 // Change `100` to however many messages you want to fetch.
}).then((messages) => {
  const messagesToDelete = [];
  // Use filter to find message by the spammer by id.
  messages.filter(m => m.author.id === THE_SPAMMERS_ID_HERE).forEach(msg => messagesToDelete.push(msg));
  // Delete the spam messages here.
  message.channel.bulkDelete(messagesToDelete).then(() => {
    message.channel.send("Messages deleted.").then(msg => msg.delete({
      timeout: 3000
    }))
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try.

```
  const Messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1000 });
  Messages.forEach(msg => {
    if (msg.author.id == "spammers id here") msg.delete();
  });
```

Comment: .then() does not need await.